# Error with Instance profile role for EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-emr

I am trying to build an EMR cluster through terraform. But I am getting following error on applying the code. IAM_EMR_for_EC2 is the instance profile role I created for EC2 in the cluster to assume.

> 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> - aws_emr_cluster.tf-test-cluster: 1 error(s) occurred:
> - aws_emr_cluster.tf-test-cluster: ValidationException: Instance profile 'arn:aws:iam:::role/IAM_EMR_for_EC2' is not
>     well-formed. Expected a resource of type INSTANCE_PROFILE.
>         status code: 400, request id: 6bd4461c-637f-11e8-8605-c930816c10b8

Could someone help me as I am not able to understand this error nor I could it find any details on google.

Comment: Can you provide some example terraform code? That would help in finding out what might be wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're applying a role rather than an instance profile, they are actually different. The ARN needs to be in the format of `arn:aws:iam::336924118301:instance-profile/ExampleInstanceProfile`.

A role needs to be attached to an instance profile resource.

Answer (score 2):

You should write `instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.emr_profile.arn}"`.

And also create emr_profile resource:
`resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "emr_profile" {
        name  = "emr_profile"
        role = "${aws_iam_role.EMR_EC2_DefaultRole.name}"
}`